# Command to print host and current working directory

Tags: bash

`pwd` will print current working directory. Is there a terminal command to print the current working host *and* directory so you can just dump it into /etc/fstab as a mount point?

Comment: Like that `echo $(hostname) $(pwd)`?

Comment: and `echo $HOSTNAME $PWD`

Comment: As a mountpoint? Are you using an NFS mount or something that you want to add to `fstab`? If so, look into `findmnt` with its multiple output formatting options